# how to transfer the mysql subquery to left join?

Tags: mysql

how to translate the sub query to left join?

```
SELECT * FROM  member  
WHERE shop_id = 3215138 AND grade = 2  
AND nick NOT IN (
    SELECT `buyer_nick` FROM item 
    WHERE shop_id=3215138 AND num_iid IN (23696088262, 522953128382)
);
```

the table struct is follow:

```
mysql> DESCRIBE member

+--------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field              | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| member_id          | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| shop_id            | int(11)      | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| nick               | varchar(255) | NO   |     |         |                |
| name               | varchar(255) | NO   |     |         |                |
| mobile             | varchar(255) | NO   |     |         |                |
| grade              | int(11)      | NO   |     | -1      |                |
| created            | int(11)      | NO   |     |         |                |
| modified           | int(11)      | NO   |     |         |                |
+--------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+


    CREATE TABLE `member` (
  `member_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `shop_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `nick` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `grade` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '-1',
  `created` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`member_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `shop_id` (`shop_id`,`nick`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8


mysql> DESCRIBE item;
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id         | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| shop_id    | int(11)      | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| buyer_nick | varchar(255) | NO   |     |         |                |
| num_iid    | bigint(11)   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| num        | int(11)      | NO   |     | 0       |                |
| times      | int(11)      | NO   |     | 0       |                |
| created    | int(11)      | NO   |     | 0       |                |
| modified   | int(11)      | NO   |     | 0       |                |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

CREATE TABLE `item` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `shop_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `buyer_nick` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `num_iid` bigint(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Tobao ItemID',
  `num` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `created` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `uniqk` (`shop_id`,`buyer_nick`,`num_iid`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

note: the item.buyer_nick who own the query num_iid can also own the other num_iid;  I have try :

```
SELECT * FROM  member  AS m 
    LEFT JOIN item AS i 
    ON m.nick=i.buyer_nick
    WHERE m.shop_id = 3215138 AND i.shop_id=3215138 AND m.grade=2 
    AND i.num_iid NOT IN (23696088262, 522953128382)
```

and the result still own the buyer_nick who has num_iid (23696088262, 522953128382) and other num_iid, not equal the subquery result;

example data:

table member data:

```
| member_id | shop_id | nick |grade |  created    |
| 1         |  3215138|  A   |   2  |   1540968764|
| 2         |  3215138|  B   |   2  |   1540968764|
| 3         |  3215138|  C   |   2  |   1540968764|
```

table item data:

```
|id| shop_id|  buyer_nick|  num_iid    |num|  created  |
|1 | 3215138|  A         | 23696088262 | 3 |1540968764 | 
|2 | 3215138|  A         | 522953128382| 2 |1540968764 | 
|3 | 3215138|  A         | 123456789   | 2 |1540968764 |
```

the subquery result  is nick  B, C row  (NOT INCLUDE A)

Comment: What is the join relationship between the two tables ?

Comment: Could you do more searching on  how the mysql join works.

Comment: Please provide a relevant and minimal sample data showcasing your requirements, and expected output. Refer this link on how to frame a good SQL question: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/2469308)

Comment: We generally prefer SHIW CREATE TABLE statements to DESCRIBE statements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try below using left join

- From the table structure, the relation key between these two tables
  are `member.nick and buyer_nick`
- Left join and putting all other conditions in on clause gives you all
  rows but when you define `buyer_nick is null` condition in where
  clause it will give you those nick which are not present in item
  table

Using

```
SELECT * FROM  member left join item on member.nick= item.`buyer_nick`
and member.shop_id = 3215138 AND member.grade = 2  
where item.`buyer_nick` is null
```

Comment: Syntax errors in your query; and even pseudo code is outright wrong.

Comment: Yes I've missed the alias name and that's the syntax error. @MadhurBhaiya what is point of giving me downvote.. You can easily tell me that this is wrong - if it really wrong I can delete the answer. But you always first downvote me. Do you think giving downvote is more appreciable in this community ?

Comment: First of all, answer is still wrong. Downvoting is my prerogative; if I feel that an answer is outright wrong (and with no explanation). Since you said that you want reason for a downvote; I have given the reason. If Stackoverflow wanted no downvote; this right would not have been given to the community. Feel free to read on meta: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=downvote+bad+answers

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya, I can understand it that giving downvote is your right :) but I would like to know where the code is wrong then you know I can learn it from you. After all SO is the place for learning

Comment: For starters, you can fix the syntax errors. Run it through any online syntax checking tool for SQL. Secondly, question has a `NOT IN` clause; while yours is other way around. Without proper join relationships defined, your answer is nothing but a wild (and bad) guess. So, in this case it is nothing but a bad [FGIWP](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/97310)

Looking at downvotes; one more person seem to agree with me.

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya, Yes now I also fully agree with u, thank you for your proper explanation

Comment: I have edited your answer to remove syntax errors; and made it unambiguous. So I have removed my downvote; however I feel that answer is still wrong conceptually; but OP has not made it clear either.

Comment: thanks a  lot , but still not equal the subquery result yet , if  a buyer_nick called A has num_iid  23696088262 and also has another num_iid  123456, the query you given  will include A, but  the subquery will ignore   A.

Comment: @Jackhe, can you please provide your sample data for these two tables in the question

Comment: @fa06 , the sample data has push.

Comment: after  experiment， this query is what I  need, thanks a lot. @fao6